# 1and1 doesn´t work with homepage not but works pages in controllers

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to publish a webpage in 1and1 but i have some problems with it, and i don´t know if is the `.htacces` or other thing.

The page works with domain.com/home but doesn´t work with domain.com

I tried to use a redirect from 1and1 but when I am trying to load the page says "to many redirects"

then, this is my `.haccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/images|/js|/css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

thanks

edit1: and the error is this: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# 1y1
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.DOMINIO\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/DOMINIO\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```